# What’s the difference between “there’s someone doing something” and “someone is doing something”?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

They are lines from *Chicago*.

*There’s Bernie lying on the couch.*

*I come back, open the door, and there's Veronica and Charlie doing number 17, the spread-eagle.*

Do the two constructions have different emphasis?

Comment: I assume the speaker is metaphorically pointing to Bernie, Veronica and Charlie. 'When I walk in, that's what I see.'

Comment: @ Kate Bunting So you mean it’s actually a creative and unusual expression?